# Como fazer esse grid com bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer esse grid com bootstrap mas sem sucesso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer com table html e div:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: E como tentou? Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código?

Comment: Vc esta usando Bootstrap 3 ou quer na versão 4?

Comment: To usando Bootstrap 3

Comment: Front edita a sua pergunta e coloca mais detalhes para ela ser votada para ser reaberta ok. Eu já tenho uma resposta para vc usando apenas o Grid do Bootstrap 3, mas enquanto a pergunta estiver fecha não consigo postar a resposta. Tente edita-la com o grid que vc tentou fazer o uma explicação melhor que eu posto a resposta pra vc. []´s

Comment: @hugocsl editei a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: Legal, votei pra reabrir, vamos ver se ela volta, ai posto o código pra vc. Mas se vc quiser ir tentando, vc tem que fazer uma div por fora que encapsula as 4 primeiras rows, depois com css vc trara a col da imagem. Não precisa de table!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver vc pode agrupar as 4 primeiras `Rows` em um *container*. No caso o meu eu chamei de `Wrapper` como vc vai ver no CSS. Depois eu usei a class `.col2` para definir o comportamento da imagem que na verdade é o *background* de uma `col-xs-2` que tem `position:absolut` e `height de 100%` ***para ficar sempre da altura do Wrapper***. Isso significa que se vc quiser 8 Rows dentro do Wrapper a imagem continua ocupando a altura toda!

**OBS 1:** Os estilos que eu usei em `[class^=col-]` são apenas para vc poder visualizar o formato do Grid. Já as classer .wrapper e .col2 vc vai precisar!

**OBS2:** Eu coloquei o Grid inteiro dentro da classe default do Bootstrap `.container`, mas se vc quiser que o *Grid* ocupe 100% da largura da tela basta remover a `div.container` ok.

```css
[class^=col-] {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.col2 {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/200/200);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col2">.col-xs-2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">.col-xs-12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```